# Kogrid Column reordering is not working in mozilla firefox

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, durandal, kogrid

I am using koGrid in my web page. Everything is works fine in Chrome, but when it comes to Fire fox and safari the Column reordering is not working. I had written following code:
in js file

```
 self.gridOptions = {
    data: self.reportData,
    columnDefs: [
       { field: 'Invoice', displayName: 'Month' },
       { field: 'ContactName', displayName: 'Date' },
       { field: 'DueDate', displayName: 'Due Date' },
       { field: 'TranDate', displayName: 'Tran Date' },
       { field: 'BOLNumber', displayName: 'BOL#' },
       { field: 'TranID', displayName: 'Tran Number' },
       { field: 'PRONumber', displayName: 'PRO#' },
       { field: 'ReferenceNo', displayName: 'REF#' },
       { field: 'Charge', displayName: 'Charge' },
       { field: 'OpenAmount', displayName: 'Open Amount' },
       { field: 'Balance', displayName: 'Balance' },
       { field: 'TranType', displayName: 'tranType' }
    ]
 };
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

My application is a SPA application using durandal, and Knockout.

Is there any thing that I have to add in configuration?

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in FF, I tried with both my own app and this example

http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/examples

Comment: I changed my code like following:
Added  "jqueryUIDraggable: true," in koGrid object. and also added Jquery-ui.js in my page but still not working.. :(